# Merge [browsing] and [multiple-browsers] into [browser]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I think these tags are too similar to be different tags. [browsing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browsing) and [browser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser) are basically the same, and if the purpose of [multiple-browsers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-browsers) is to be more general (not browser-specific) then I think [browser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser) is general enough. If it's something else (maybe using multiple browsers simultaneously for something) then we can clean some of the questions tagged with it, but I think it's pretty useless.

Comment: As well as [browser-cache] - it only has 55 questions.